# print a pdf file with large scale and in landscape orientation?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printing, landscape

I have windows 7 and adobe acrobat. 
I want to print a PDF file with text and I need to print with for example 200 percentage with landscape, but I can print only upper half of the page and the second half I miss in print. How can I fix this, I mean, when I want each printed text page (with twice size) with two halves each in separate paper.

Any help appreciated.

P.S. I do not want to take snapshot for each half page and copy it in Word and print it, as it takes long time.

Comment: What kind of print settings do you use? And what kind of paper size?

Comment: I have printer that has A4 papers, and I need each half of every page will be printed in separate paper with almost twice size of the fonts to be readable from far. of course I need them in landscape instead of portrait.

Comment: @asad Adobe Reader XI has a print-function "Poster" which should help you.